# split string in to rows in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a string in sql `ABCDEF` . This is coming under `First_Name` column in a `EMP` table.
I want to split this string into rows as give below.

Please note there is no delimiter or Comma or space. Its a string without any special characters and special symbols and space.

```
First_Name
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? This is a very unusual request. String processing is far easier on the client side or as part of an ETL script. Using one row per letter is also very unusual

Comment: yes, please be more clear about what you need

Comment: What is the real problem you are trying to solve? You could probably solve it in a much easier way

Comment: You want to do this for one user or all users?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4):

A loop obviously comes to mind but we can do much better. This is where a tally or numbers table is perfect. I have a view in my system like this which creates such a table with 10,000 rows on demand. There are plenty of ways to create such a table, or you could create a persistent table for a slight performance gain.

```
create View [dbo].[cteTally] as

WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )
select N from cteTally
```

Now that we have the view this type of thing is super painless using a totally set based approach and abandoning the idea of looping.

```
declare @Something varchar(20) = 'ABCDEF'

select SUBSTRING(@Something, N, 1)
from cteTally t
where t.N < LEN(@Something)
```

Answer (score 4):

Solving this is trivial if you have a [Numbers](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1) table. No loops or cursors are necessary, resulting in performance that is orders of magnitude better than other solutions:

```
declare @name varchar(10)='ABCDEF'

select @name,SUBSTRING(@name,n,1)
from numbers
where n<=LEN(@name)
```

Or

```
select EMP.First_Name,SUBSTRING(EMP.First_Name,n,1)
from EMP,numbers
where n<=LEN(EMP.First_Name)
```

A Numbers table contains only numbers from 1 to a sufficiently large number. You can create such a table with the following statement (borrowed from the linked article):

```
SELECT TOP (1000000) n = CONVERT(INT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id]))
INTO dbo.Numbers
FROM sys.all_objects AS s1 CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX n ON dbo.Numbers(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CTE to parse out each character of your string onto a new row:

```
DECLARE @data varchar(200) = 'ABCDEF'

;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        1 as CharacterPosition,
        SUBSTRING(@data,1,1) as Character
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        CharacterPosition + 1,
        SUBSTRING(@data,CharacterPosition + 1,1)
    FROM
        CTE
    WHERE CharacterPosition < LEN(@data)
)
SELECT Character
FROM CTE
```